# Comparing diagonal elements of (2-fold) inverses of positive definite matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, trace, positive-definite

> Suppose $M$ is a real positive definite matrix, and $\Lambda$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix, then does the following inequality always hold?
>   $$(M^{-2})_{ii} - ((M + \Lambda)^{-2})_{ii} \ge 0$$
>   where $(\cdot)_{ii}$ denotes the $(i,i)$-element, and $M$ satisfies that:
>   1). All the off-diagonal elements of $M$ are $\le 0$;
>   2). $M$ has its row sums all $ > 1$, or in notations: 
>   $$(M)_{ii} +\sum_{j\ne i} (M)_{ij}> 1$$
>   (If you want more context, $M$ is a laplacian matrix plus a positive diagonal matrix.)

Intuitively $(M + \Lambda)$ should be "more positive definite" than $M$, and $(M+\Lambda)^{-2}$ "less positive definite" than $M^{-2}$... but I don't know how to start at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumptions on $M$ can be relaxed. Forget the row sums of $M$. Suppose $M$ is symmetric positive definite and it has non-positive off-diagonal entries. Then $M+D$ is an [M-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix) for any nonnegative diagonal matrix $D$. Hence $(M+D)^{-1}>0$ entrywise.

Now, if $M$ is an M-matrix and $D$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix with exactly one nonzero (and positive) diagonal entry, then $M^{-1}>(M+D)^{-1}$ entrywise. This is a direct consequence of [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) (and the fact that $M^{-1}$ is both entrywise positive and positive definite).

So, if $\Lambda$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix, by applying Sherman-Morrison formula repeatedly, we get $M^{-1}\ge(M+\Lambda)^{-1}$ entrywise (the inequality is actually strict if $\Lambda$ is nonzero). In turn, $M^{-2}=(M^{-1})^2\ge\left(M+\Lambda)^{-1}\right)^2=(M+\Lambda)^{-2}$.

Comment: Thanks but I don't quite follow your last equation. Does squaring preserve entrywise inequality?

Comment: @Vim Yes, because both sides are positive. If $A\ge B$, then $(A^2)_{ij}=\sum_ka_{ik}a_{kj}\ge\sum_kb_{ik}b_{kj}=(B^2)_{ij}$.